# Show subtitle into another element HTML5

Tags: html, html5-video, subtitle

I have the following code for playing a video and showing its subtitle track.

```html
<video id="vTest" class="playr_video" controls preload="metadata">
       <source src='upc-tobymanley.theora.ogg' type='video/ogg'>
       <source src='upc-tobymanley.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
       <track label="English subtitles" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="upc-video-subtitles-en.vtt" default>
   </video>
<div id="subtitle"> </div>
```

Is it possible to show the subtitles inside `<div id="subtitle"> </div>` instead  of the player?

Answer (score 0):

Add this javaScript after `<video>` element

```
<script>

loadTextTrack({videoId:'vTest', // the ID of the video tag
               kind:'subtitles', // the kind of track
               srclang:'en', // the language of the source file (optional)
               targetId:'subtitle'}); // the ID of the element into which to insert the timed text
</script>
```

Define some css

```
<style type="text/css">

#subtitle{width: 480px; position: absolute; top: 280px;padding: 3px 10px; text-align:  center; color:#fff;background-color:#000; font-family:  Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 0.9em; font-weight: bold;min-height:3.6em;}

</style>
```

Comment: Tested,Throws an error "ReferenceError: loadTextTrack is not defined"

Comment: Add these two lines to the <head> section.....<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="html5texttrack.js"></script>

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: track[kind=subtitles][srclang=opt['srclang']] i am getting this error,any guss why?